# How this attribute with an underscore in my model get convert to dash-separated words?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have a serializer with a model `Book` instance.

I gave my `serializer` instance to

`ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::JsonApi.new(serializer)` class, where `serializer` is my instance.

The above method call returned this

```
#<ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::JsonApi:0x000000000b515b48 @serializer=#<BookSerializer:0x0000000008496a30 @object=#<Book id: 8, type: "Book", created_at: "2018-09-18 10:25:55", updated_at: "2018-09-18 10:25:55">, @instance_options={:scope}, @root=nil, @scope=nil, @serializer_class=BookSerializer, @attributes={:id=>8, :email=>"random@exam.com", :author=>"user1", :created_at=>Tue, 18 Sep 2018 10:25:55}, @_config={}>, @instance_options={}, @include_directive=#<JSONAPI::IncludeDirective:0x000000000b515aa8 @hash={}, @options={:allow_wildcard=>true}>, @fieldset=#<ActiveModel::Serializer::Fieldset:0x000000000b5159e0 @raw_fields={}>>
```

Then I tried to call `serializable_hash` on the Adapter class instance as below

`ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::JsonApi.new(serializer).serializable_hash`

Above call returned this

```
{:data=>{:id=>"8", :type=>"books", :attributes=>{:email=>"random@exam.com", :author=>"user1", :"created-at"=>Tue, 18 Sep 2018 10:25:55 UTC +00:00}, :relationships=>{:"book"=>{:data=>{:id=>"15", :type=>"books"}}}}}
```

The above-returned data have `created_at` converted to `created-at`.

What is happening when I call serializable_hash in the adapter class instance?

Answer (score 0):

**Serializable Hash** returns a serialized hash of your object.

```
book = Book.new
book.title = 'Legends'
book.content  = 'Once upon a time, in a far away galaxy'
book.serializable_hash # => {"title"=>"Legends", "content"=>"Once upon a time, in a far away galaxy"}
```

Reference check [this](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serialization/serializable_hash) out

Comment: That I understood, but why does the above attribute changes from `created_at` to `created-at`.

Comment: I believe, the standard JsonApi uses is `dashes` rather than `underscores`. The only workaround I know off is, do you have file `active_model_serializers.rb` under `config` directory ? Add the following lines in the file `ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = ActiveModel::Serializer::Adapter::JsonApi`
`ActiveModelSerializers.config.key_transform = :underscore`

Comment: Yeah. Under config file, and have this line in it
`ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json`

Comment: You need to add `ActiveModelSerializers.config.key_transform = :underscore` to `active_model_serializers.rb`